# stack level too deep : SystemStackError

Tags: ruby

I am trying to execute following code:

```
class Array

    def each
        for i in self
            yield(i)
       end
    end

end

[1,2,3,4].each {|i| puts i*i}
```

when i run this code i get following error:

```
stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

But following code execute successfully:

```
class Array

    def each
            yield(self[0])
            yield(self[1])
            yield(self[2])
            yield(self[3])
    end

end

[1,2,3,4].each {|i| puts i*i}
```

Output:

```
1
4
9
16
```

Comment: I think it’s because `for…in` uses `each` internally so you’re creating recursion. Try naming your method so it does not clash with a built-in method.

Comment: yes it works if i change 'each' to 'aech'

Comment: If the point of this exercise is to learn how to implement `each` on your own, then you are simply cheating. You are basically just calling the built-in `each` again, just in the disguise of `for`/`in`.

Answer (score 0):

`for` loop calls `each` under the hood.

Reference:

- http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/ (List of Ruby 1.9 keywords)
- http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-for+Loop (Official documentation of Control Expressions)